# How to create dynamic functionality using Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a page which has multiple order buttons (One for each menu item). When an order is placed I want to call a Javascript function to change only the order button pressed rather than every button with the ID. There *has to be* better implementation for these function calls... Anyone?

```js
function orderFood1(helpVal) { 
  if (document.getElementById("food1").innerHTML === "Order") {
    document.getElementById("food1").innerHTML = "&#9989;";
 // Alert waiter
  } else {
    document.getElementById("food1").innerHTML = "Order";
 // Cancel Request
  }
}

function orderFood2(helpVal) { 
  if (document.getElementById("food2").innerHTML === "Order") {
    document.getElementById("food2").innerHTML = "&#9989;";
 // Alert waiter
  } else {
    document.getElementById("food2").innerHTML = "Order";
 // Cancel Request
  }
}

function orderFood3(helpVal) { 
  if (document.getElementById("food3").innerHTML === "Order") {
    document.getElementById("food3").innerHTML = "&#9989;";
 // Alert waiter
  } else {
    document.getElementById("food3").innerHTML = "Order";
 // Cancel Request
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="food1" onclick="orderFood1()" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>

<button type="button" id="food2" onclick="orderFood2()" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>

<button type="button" id="food3" onclick="orderFood3()" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can create the following html code:

```
<button type="button" id="food1" onclick="orderFood('food1')" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>

<button type="button" id="food2" onclick="orderFood('food2')" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
```

Which means that you use only single `orderFood` function, that gets the ID of the `button` element as a parameter.

And then your JS code could be something like this:

```
function orderFood(foodId) { 
  if (document.getElementById(foodId).innerHTML === "Order") {
    document.getElementById(foodId).innerHTML = "&#9989;";
    // Alert waiter
  } else {
    document.getElementById(foodId).innerHTML = "Order";
    // Cancel Request
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They all look to do nearly the same thing, so you can use only a single function. To identify which button was clicked, you can examine the clicked button from the listener - the target of the event. Also, best to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) - attach the listeners properly using Javascript instead.

Since you're only inserting text, it'd be more appropriate to retrieve and assign to the `textContent` of the element, rather than its `innerHTML`.

```js
const handleOrder = ({ target }) => {
  if (target.textContent === 'Order') {
    target.textContent = '✅';
    console.log('Alerting waiter');
  } else {
    target.textContent = "Order";
    console.log('Canceling request');
  }
};

for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleOrder);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order</button>
```

Comment: This may work, but I have a lot more buttons which are used for different purposes (e.g Drink Orders, Drink Refills, Play games, etc) I'll give it a try. It may only require additional handling functions, correct?

Comment: It depends on what exactly goes on when those other buttons are clicked, but you can probably put all the logic into a single function which checks which type of button was clicked and carries out the appropriate logic for that button.

Comment: If you wanted to see the entire context, the full repository is located at:

https://github.com/FabledKnight/hello-world/tree/master/web/index.html

The entire project is still in the beginning phase, so a lot of changes still need to be made.